# Accessing a row of a std::mdspan as std::span

Tags: c++, c++23, mdspan

I'm trying out the [Kokkos reference mdspan implementation](https://github.com/kokkos/mdspan) to see if it could be used to simplify some bits of code in our codebase. One thing that I would have intuitively assumed to be possible is to pick a row of a two dimensional `std::mdspan` and assign it to a `std::span`, e.g. somewhat like

```
float* data = ...

std::mdspan matrix (data, 2, 5);

std::span vector = matrix[0]; // <-- should be a std::span<float, std::dynamic_extent> viewing row 0 of matrix
```

After some research I didn't find an obvious straightforward way to achieve that, neither with member functions of mdspan nor with free functions from the std library. The only possibility I see at the moment I going back to the raw pointer level and write my own free functions to do that, which is not really as elegant as I expected. Am I overlooking something or is that really no feature of mdspan?

Comment: Maybe [`submdspan`](https://github.com/kokkos/mdspan/blob/stable/include/experimental/__p2630_bits/submdspan.hpp) can help.

Comment: Thanks, but this does not offer direct conversion to `std::span`, right?

Comment: The `5` can not conveniently be a template parameter because it is a runtime variable. By providing the 5 to the constructor of `matrix` there is no reasonable way to make the `mdspan` aware at compile time that the second extent always has 5 elements. The best you can do here is `std::span<float, std::dynamic_extent>`.

Comment: Ah yes of course @Mestkon. I'm aware of that, fixed it in the question above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can slice the original 2d-`mdspan` into a 1-d `mdspan` through C++26 [`std::submdspan()`](https://eel.is/c++draft/mdspan.submdspan.submdspan).

Since the underlying sequence of result `mdspan` is contiguous, it can be used to construct the `std::span`

```
float* data = ...;

std::mdspan matrix(data, 2, 5);

std::mdspan row0 = std::submdspan(matrix, 0, std::full_extent);
std::span vector0(row0.data_handle(), row0.size()); // row 0 of matrix

std::mdspan row1 = std::submdspan(matrix, 1, std::full_extent);
std::span vector1(row1.data_handle(), row1.size()); // row 1 of matrix
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/qj8bv9bvE) using [reference `mdspan` implementation](https://github.com/kokkos/mdspan).